# mySQL ORDER based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql

My actual table is much more in-depth than this but let's assume I have a table that looks like this...

```
Record_ID     Due_Date     Style
=========     ==========   =====
100           2018-01-01   10
101           2018-01-02   20
102           2018-01-03   12
103           2018-01-04   10
104           2018-01-05   20
105           2018-01-06   12
106           2018-01-02   10
```

What I want is a query that will determine the first due date and then return that record along with all other records with the same style regardless of the due date. It should then be followed by the next due date of another style and keep going. A successful output would be in this order...

```
Record_ID     Due_Date     Style
=========     ==========   =====
100           2018-01-01   10
106           2018-01-02   10
103           2018-01-04   10
101           2018-01-02   20
104           2018-01-05   20
102           2018-01-03   12
105           2018-01-06   12
```

If you look at just the first record for each `Style` the output is in order.
See records 100,101,102

If you look at all the records for a given `Style` the output is sorted by date.
See records 100,106,103

If you look at just the `Style` column the output is has all the like `Style` together but not necessarily in numerical order.

By doing having this output, it is easy to see what `Style` is due first but all records in that same `Style` will be completed prior to moving on to the next `Style`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using a subquery that creates a grouping of styles with their corresponding `min(duedate)`.  Then you `join` that back to the original table and `order by` that date.

```
select *
from yourtable t join (
  select min(duedate) minduedate, style
  from yourtable
  group by style) t2 on t.style = t2.style
order by t2.minduedate, t.duedate
```

- [Online Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dMGgGDYw6eyu6Bn281oZge/0)

Comment: Works great! Thanks @sgeddes